# Android - Copy native libraries from APK into application internal directory during installation

Tags: android, installation, apk

I have an APK with some native libraries. When the app installs, it is available in /data/app//lib/. 
But my requirement is that some of the native libraries must be present in application internal location (/data/data//files). 
How to achieve this so that the libraries are copied to the app internal location during installation itself.